# How to run python with SimpleHttpRequestHandler

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I'm using python3.
I want to show a one page but I got 404 not found file:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import http.server
import socketserver
from furl import furl



class MyServer(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print("jkjhjkhk") #printed
        print(self.path)
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = './desktop/formdailyactivities/index.html'
        else:
            self.send_response(200)
            print (self.path)
            f = furl(self.path)
            
            # activity = f.args["activity"]
            # time = f.args["time"]
            # date = f.args["date"]

            # print(activity)
            # print(time)
            # print(date)

            
           # s1.insert(activity, time, date)
        return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)


handler_object = MyServer

PORT = 8080
my_server = socketserver.TCPServer(("",PORT), handler_object)
my_server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 2):

After testing your full code I can run it when I use `self.path = "index.html"` or `self.path = "folder/index.html"` but only if `"folder/index.html"` is inside folder in which I run code.

It can be for security reason. It may not read files which are below/outside folder in which I run code because someone could use path ie. `../../etc/passwd` to steal passwords.

As I know server `Apache` also restricts access to folders which are below/outside running folder.
All server should restric it.

You may have to write own code which read data from file and send to browser.

---

You can get path to file with `http.server` to see source code

```
print(http.server.__file__)
```

maybe it helps you.

In source code I saw function `copyfile` which it uses to send file.

---

Frankly, I would rathern use `Flask` to create it.

---

**EDIT:**

After digging in source code I can see that original `do_GET` use `translate_path()` to convert `path` into `current_folder/path` which can be incorrect and it can't find file.

Using code from source code I create this version - it runs almost all code from original `do_GET` except `translate_path()` so I can use absolute path to display file.

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import os

#print('source code for "http.server":', http.server.__file__)

class MyServer(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    
    def do_GET(self):

        print(self.path)
        
        if self.path == '/':
            #self.path = '/home/furas/test/index.html'
            self.path = './desktop/formdailyactivities/index.html'
            
            print('original  :', self.path)
            print('translated:', self.translate_path(self.path))
            
            try:
                f = open(self.path, 'rb')
            except OSError:
                self.send_error(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND, "File not found")
                return None

            ctype = self.guess_type(self.path)
            fs = os.fstat(f.fileno())
            
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", ctype)
            self.send_header("Content-Length", str(fs[6]))
            self.send_header("Last-Modified",
                self.date_time_string(fs.st_mtime))
            self.end_headers()            
            
            try:
                self.copyfile(f, self.wfile)
            finally:
                f.close()
                
        else:
            # run normal code
            print('original  :', self.path)
            print('translated:', self.translate_path(self.path))
            super().do_GET()
    
# --- main ---

handler_object = MyServer

PORT = 8080

print(f'Starting: http://localhost:{PORT}')

try:
    socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True  # solution for `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`
    my_server = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), handler_object)
    my_server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # solution for `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use - when stoped by Ctr+C
    print('Stoped by "Ctrl+C"')
finally:
    # solution for `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
    print('Closing')
    my_server.server_close()
```

Comment: I think when I enter this url : `http://localhost:8080/test?activity=&time=&date=` I should see print inside of `else`. but I got 404 not found page.

Comment: I run my code by : `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`

Comment: when you run `test?activity=&time=&date=` then it searchs file or folder with name `test` - do you have it ? If you don't have it then it shows `404 not found page.`

Comment: when you runs `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` then it runs standard class `SimpleHTTPServer` - not your code - so it can't run code in `else`. You should run as `python your_script.py`