# Python Web Server diferent folders in desktop and laptop

Tags: python, python-3.x, webserver

I'm making a simple web server following the [documentaction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http-server-cli) . The idea is to make the server without install any additional module.

The matter is work perfect in desktop computers but in laptops it shares system32 folder instead the folder where the file is located. I've tried with several desktops and laptops, and always happen the same. Same OS: Windows 10

I don't understand why the result change based on type of computer (and how the program know).
Any idea?

I attach the code:

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import socket 

port= 8000

handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

address_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", port), handler) as server:
    print(f" Server address IP: | {address_ip}:{port} |")
    print(f"       (Press Ctrl+C to close)\n")
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nServer stoped by user.")
input("\nPress Enter to exit...")
```

Comment: Hey, it would probably be easier for people to answer your question if your variables were english based. In general, it's a good practice to use english in your code (the parts that aren't printed to user at least).

Comment: @Marko, sorry I'm spanish and just copy my code, just edited the code to put everything in english. Thats for the comment.

Comment: Can you add an example of how you run this code?

Comment: You can set the path explicitly  if you wanted. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67359204/how-to-run-python-with-simplehttprequesthandler

Comment: @JonSG thanks, interesting, but I would like to work as that, from the located folder, as kind of "portable web server". What really intrigues me is why it works differently depending on the device....

Comment: @Marko, I´ve prepared an screenshot 1st in a desktop, and 2nd in a laptop. I attach you a link to the image: https://i.ibb.co/HH56psm/Web-Server.png

Comment: I meant how do you start this code? What is the command you type into your terminal, or what do you click to get it started?
p.s. You didn't block the your IP in your requests, but `192.168` is left for internal use, so you don't need to hide it.

Comment: @Marko To run the program,I just execute "python servidorweb.py" where servidorweb.py is the program name.

Comment: So it seems that the problem is in what Python considers the "current directory" when being run on different machines. Can you add `print os.getcwd()` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.getcwd in your script and share the results?

Comment: Of course @Marko. In the desktop, the folder is D:\GitHub\CODIGO\Python (OK), in the laptop the folder is c:\Windows\system32 (should be c:\Programs\Python). In both cases is the same program, just copy from desktop to laptop.

If I move the file to another location (for example the Desktop), in the desktop appear the new location (good) but in laptop maintain the c:\Windows\system32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get a solution, thanks @Marko for the hint.

By some reason in certain computers the python working directory use the one where the script is located and others change to System32. (Possibly something about users rights, although I always execute as Admin.)
Whatever.

To correct I've to change the working directory to the one that script is located.

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])))
```

With this command it detects the folder of the script and by [os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) change the directory to the one of the script.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that your laptop Python installation sets its working directory to `c:\Windows\system32` regardless of where you start it. It might also have something to do with the way you are starting your script, but I won't go deeper into that. One way to solve your problem, is to set the directory from where your server will serve files to the directory your script is located in. You can do it by changing your `handler` object to this line:

```
import partial from functools
handler = partial(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Just note, this means that if you are starting your script from some other location, it will again fallback to the script location, which is something your users might not expect.

Comment: Good idea @marko, but the problem that functools is not embedded module and I want the program be portable, this is, "without installs". 

Following your idea I'm going to try with `os`, maybe with something similar to this: `handler= http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler (directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__) )``

Crossing the fingers

Comment: `functools` comes installed with Python https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Version 3.11.5. The VSC import functools happy but when you insert 'import partial from functools' it complaints that "Import "partial" could not be resolved"

Comment: Could you try `import functools` and use `functools.partial` in your code.

Comment: Already solved with 'os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])))', don't need to use functools